# Write dataframe to MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns, I want to write the dataframe to the database, when it gets to the ninth row, it throws an error and i am not sure why.

`DataError: (pymysql.err.DataError) (1264, "Out of range value for column 'TGT_ENDBALANCE' at row 9")`

Here is my dataframe

```
    GROSS_AMOUNT    TGT_ENDBALANCE
0   0.00    2.982305e+08
1   4.00    3.017238e+09
2   5.00    3.117889e+09
3   0.00    3.446241e+08
4   3.00    2.896071e+09
5   100.00  1.033510e+06
6   0.00    3.676000e+04
7   0.00    2.699448e+09
8   6.00    2.327800e+10
9   1.00    3.011000e+04
10  5.00    2.715292e+09
11  96.00   2.247000e+06
12  5.00    -1.292000e+11
13  10.00   2.707742e+09
14  20.00   2.089900e+05
15  10.00   4.361500e+05
16  5.00    2.918166e+09

df.to_sql(tableName, con=dbConnection, if_exists='replace', index=False,
         dtype={'GROSS_AMOUNT': sqlalchemy.types.NUMERIC(),
                'TGT_ENDBALANCE': sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR()})
```

Here is my column in the table on mysql

```
TGT_ENDBALANCE       | varchar(220,0) | YES  |     | NULL
```

I have changed the column type to string, bigint, varchar and all the datatypes but still no luck.

Comment: My Guess something is 32bit and `2.327800e+10` will not fit in an 32bit integer

Comment: I have tried all the other datatypes including varchar and string. What would you suggest please?

Comment: Are you running 32bit python?

Comment: My python version is Python 3.6.6

Comment: but is it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: it is 64 please